# Replacing class with a functional component in a hook to subtract props from T

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

The hook has to subtract props from T. This is done successfully in `withHook` function using a class. However, how to do the same in `withHookFn` function using a function.

Code has further comments within.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {Subtract} from "utility-types";
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

interface upperMsgProps {
  msg: string;
}

class upperMsg extends React.Component<upperMsgProps & someProps> {
  render() {
    return <div>msg is: {this.props.msg} / boo is: {this.props.boo}</div>;
  }
}
// replacing withHook with withHookFn breaks the code with error:
// "Property 'boo' is missing in type '{ msg: string; }' but required in type 'someProps'" - this is because in withHookFn Subtract does not 'someProps' out 'T'
const UpperMsgWHOC = withHook(upperMsg);

function App() {
  return <UpperMsgWHOC msg={"asd"}/>;
}

interface someProps {
  boo: string;
}

function withHook<T extends someProps>(WComp: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  return class extends React.Component<Subtract<T, someProps>> {
    render() {
      return <WComp
        {...this.props as T}
        boo={"boo-val"}
      />;
    }
  };
}

// withHook works fine but how to do the same without using a class - by just using a functional component
function withHookFn<T extends someProps>(WComp: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  // how to make this Subtract work with function because this is not working ...
  return function (props: T): React.ReactElement<Subtract<T, someProps>> {
    return <WComp
      {...props as T}
      boo={"boo-val"}
    />;
  };
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(<App />);
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: Subtract has to be done for props argument in functional component.

```js
function withHookFn<T extends someProps>(WComp: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  // this now works!
  return function (props: <Subtract<T, someProps>>) {
    return <WComp
      {...props as T}
      boo={"boo-val"}
    />;
  };
}
```